# char digit to integer conversion

Tags: java

I'm getting the user to enter a string of numbers, then a for loop should pick out each number from the string and add it to an `ArrayList`. I'm sure someone can help me out fairly quickly

My problem is as follows. When I print out all the values in the `ArrayList`, It is printing out much higher numbers e.g. `1234 = 49 50 51 52`.

I think what is happening is that it is printing out the `ASCII` values rather than the numbers themselves. Can anyone spot where and why this is happening?

I have tried changing the `int` variable barcodeNumberAtI to a `char`, which yields the same result.

Apologies for lack of comments but this was only supposed to be a quick program

```
int tempNewDigit;
String barCode, ans;
int barcodeNumberAtI;
ArrayList <Integer> numbers = new ArrayList <Integer>();


public void addNumbers(){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
    System.out.println("Please enter a 12 digit barcode\n");
    barCode = s.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < barCode.length(); i++){

        barcodeNumberAtI = barCode.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(barcodeNumberAtI);
        numbers.add(barcodeNumberAtI);

    }

    System.out.print("Would you like to add another? y/n\n");
    ans = s.nextLine();
    } while (!ans.equals("n"));     
}

public void displayNumbers(){

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(numbers.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: The barCode entered by user is always a number?

Comment: It is supposed to be yes, I just have not added any checks to make sure that it is

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: barcodeNumberAtI should be a char, not an int. You say you tried that and it didn't work, but at present if it is an int it will be converting your chars to ints, which in java gets their ascii value. Also, your ArrayList should be of chars, not ints.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson i haven't been coding long enough to know how and where to use debuggers

Comment: @ChrisCousins I originally had a cast to add the chars to the arrayList, that is making sense now. Should I make the list a list of strings instead?

Comment: @Dylan - then now is the time to learn, did you even read the link?

Comment: Apologies, it wasn't a link for me originally. I will have a look at it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happens at this line: `barcodeNumberAtI = barCode.charAt(i);`

`barCode.charAt(i)` returns a `char` which is converted to a `int` by using its `ASCII` value.

Use this instead:

```
barcodeNumberAtI = Character.digit(barCode.charAt(i), 10);
```

What `Character.digit` does is converting its first argument from the type `char` to the corresponding `int` in the radix specified by the second argument.
[Here's a link to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,%20int))

Comment: That has worked! Can you explain what the line of code after the '=' does?

Comment: Much appreciated, Thanks!